# Get metrics via API

Tags: rest, soap, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure SQL, and there is a page in there with metrics

[image]

From what I understood the new Azure Managment Portal consumes only public apis. What I'm trying to find out is how to access these metrics via a REST or SOAP api. I've searched through the MSDN documentation but couldn't come up with anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume Microsoft did not provide Azure Database monitoring REST or SOAP API as it would not be used much.

DBAs can connect to Azure Database and gather all the necessary statistics via [dynamic management views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx) which are quite powerful.

However, I do not have any article / documentation confirming my presumptions.

Answer (score 0):

try the new sys.event_log and sys.database_connection_stats DMVs instead.

see: [Announcing: New System Views for Windows Azure SQL Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/05/announcing-new-dynamic-management-views-for-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear, but I was specifically hoping to monitor 'Throttled Connectons'.

Comment: sys.database_connection_stats returns throttled connection count as well which is the same one displayed on the portal or are you looking for something else?

Comment: But if I'm throttled I can't make the connection to the database in the first place.

Comment: then handle the throttling, it's a given that you incorporate transient fault handling when dealing with an Azure SQL Database... the portal does the same thing... besides, the information in the view is not real time and is aggregated every 5 minutes...

Comment: I have retry logic and handle error codes to spec, but that wasn't exactly what I was after...